# update view model with ajax dom elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Im working with knockout, i want to update a div content with ajax this is the code:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(datos)
        {
            $(div).empty();
            $(div).append(datos);
        },
        error: function(xhr,tipo)
        {
            alert('Ajax error!');
        }
    })
```

the ajax gives me this div appened with jquery to a "div"

```
<div class="span12">
    <a data-bind="click:transicion.bind($data,'/newPage')" class="w8-button green pull-left">Cargar un nuevo Producto</a>
</div>
```

the problem is that knockout didnt recognize the data-bind of the new element... can anybody explain me a better solution??

tnx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in your code after your page has loaded and you have created your `view model`, you are calling `ko.applyBindings()` and passing in your `view model`.

When your ajax call comes back and you append the contents to a `div`, knockout doesn't automatically know about it.  You need to call `ko.applyBindings()` passing in your `view model` and the element you want knockout to look for `data-bind` attributes in:

`ko.applyBindings( yourViewModel, document.getElementById( "yourDivId" ) )`

Or you can use any other way of getting your `div` (like jQuery selectors ).

Here is the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) on the `ko.applyBindings()` behavior.